# How to save multiple data in database by Django query set from Html table

Tags: javascript, django, forms, html-table, django-queryset

I am creating sales invoice where I create one form with two database table connections like
**sales details are saving in Sales_Invoice** table and **Items which we add in invoice will save in Item_Details** table.

So here in html form I am creating table for add items after adding that I items I wish to save sales invoice in sales_details and all items in Item_Details by using sales_invoice foreign key

My data is saving but only one row is saving How can I save multiple data in django by using queryset

Html Form

```
    <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <!-- Estimate Details -->

                <div class="row pb-3 pt-3">
                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>Invoice Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={{invoice_number}} name="invoice_number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Invoive_Date" name="invoice_date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>Select Customer</label>
                        <select id="customer_id" class="form-control" name="customer_id">
                            <option value="">Select Customer</option>
                            {% if all_customers %}
                            {% for c in all_customers %}
                            <option value="{{c.customer_id}}">{{c.first_name}} {{c.surname}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pb-3">

                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
                        <label>Contact Person Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_person_name" name="contact_person_name"
                            placeholder="Contact Person">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" name="phone">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row pb-3">

                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>Bill To</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bill To" id="bill_to"
                            name="bill_to"></textarea>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>Ship To</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ship To" id="ship_to"
                            id="ship_to"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>Special Instructions</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Special Instructions"
                            id="special_instructions" name="special_instructions"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Items -->
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto m-1 pl-2">
                            <img src="{% static 'images/GIF/Add.gif'%}" width="30px" height="30px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col mt-2">
                            <h5>Item Details</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <!-- <form> -->
                    <div class="row pb-3 pt-3">
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            <label>Item</label>
                            <select class="form-control" placeholder="Items" id="item" name="item">
                                <option value="">Item</option>
                                {% if all_items %}
                                {% for i in all_items %}
                                <option value="{{i.item}}">{{i.item}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            <label>Unit</label>
                            <select class="form-control" placeholder="Units" id="unit_name" name="unit_name">
                                <option value="">Unit</option>
                                {% if all_unit %}
                                {% for u in all_unit %}
                                <option value="{{u.unit_name}}">{{u.unit_name}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </select>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            <label>Unit Price</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit Price" id="unit_price"
                                name="unit_price">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            <label>Quantity</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" onchange="quantityChange()" id="quantity"
                                name="quantity">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            <label>HSN</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="HSN" id="hsn" name="hsn">
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            <label>Tax</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tax" id="tax_code" name="tax_code">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            <label>Amount</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Amount" id="amount" name="amount">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <P><button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-blue" id="submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- </form> -->
                </div>

                <br>

                <!-- Items table -->
                <div id="tab">
                    <div class="table-responsive-md">
                        <table class="table table-sm" style="background-color: #e4f7f5;" id="demo">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th nowrap>Items</th>
                                    <th nowrap>HSN</th>
                                    <th nowrap>Quantity</th>
                                    <th nowrap>Unit</th>
                                    <th nowrap>Unit Price</th>
                                    <th nowrap>Tax</th>
                                    <th nowrap>Amount</th>
                                    <th nowrap>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="items_tbody"></tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th id="total">Total :</th>
                                    <td id="total_value"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th id="CGST">CGST :</th>
                                    <td>200</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th id="SGST">SGST :</th>
                                    <td>200</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th id="discount">Discount :</th>
                                    <td>200</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th id="round_off">Round Off :</th>
                                    <td>200</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5"></th>
                                    <th id="grand_total">Grand Total :</th>
                                    <td>200</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Other Details -->
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto m-1 pl-2">
                            <img src="../static/images/GIF/Setting.gif" width="30px" height="30px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col mt-2">
                            <h5>Other Details</h5>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pb-3 pt-3">
                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>User</label>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={{username}} id="user" name="username">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md mb-2">
                        <label>Remarks</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks" name="remarks"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=SaveData()>Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="myDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
<br>
<scripts>
//Add Items
    var items = []; 
    $("#submit").on("click", function () {
        var temp = 
            {
            "item" : document.getElementById("item").value,
            "hsn" : document.getElementById("hsn").value,
            "quantity" : document.getElementById("quantity").value,
            "unit_name" : document.getElementById("unit_name").value,
            "unit_price" : document.getElementById("unit_price").value,
            "tax_code" : document.getElementById("tax_code").value,
            "amount":document.getElementById("amount").value,
            };
        
        items.push(temp);
        console.log(items)

        $("#demo  > tbody").empty();
        var total_amount = 0

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML+= "<tr id='row" + i +"'><td>"+items[i].item+"</td><td>"+items[i].hsn+"</td><td>"+items[i].quantity+"</td><td>"+items[i].unit_name+"</td><td>"+items[i].unit_price+"</td><td>"+items[i].tax_code+"</td><td>"+items[i].amount+"</td><td><button class='remCF1 btn btn-small btn-danger'" +
                "onClick='delRow(" + i + ")' name='delButton'>Delete</button></td></tr>"
                console.log(items[i].amount)
                items[i].amount = parseInt(items[i].amount)
                total_amount = total_amount + items[i].amount

                $('#total_value').text(total_amount);
        };
    });
    function quantityChange(){
        var base_Amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value) * parseInt(document.getElementById("unit_price").value);
        
        $("#amount").val(base_Amount);
    }
    function delRow(item) {
        this.items.splice(item, 1);
        document.getElementById("row" + item).remove();
        console.log(items)
        $("#demo > tbody").empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML+= "<tr id='row" + i +"'><td>"+items[i].item+"</td><td>"+items[i].hsn+"</td><td>"+items[i].quantity+"</td><td>"+items[i].unit_name+"</td><td>"+items[i].unit_price+"</td><td>"+items[i].tax_code+"</td><td>"+items[i].amount+"</td><td><button class='remCF1 btn btn-small btn-danger'" +
                "onClick='delRow(" + i + ")' name='delButton'>Delete</button></td></tr>"
        };

    }
    function SaveData(){
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML+= "<tr id='row" + i +"'><td>"+items[i].item+"</td><td>"+items[i].hsn+"</td><td>"+items[i].quantity+"</td><td>"+items[i].unit_name+"</td><td>"+items[i].unit_price+"</td><td>"+items[i].tax_code+"</td><td>"+items[i].amount+"</td></tr>"
        };
    }

    console.log("OUT");

</script>
```

Views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #SALES INVOICE
    invoice_number=gen_invoice_number
    invoice_date=request.POST['invoice_date']
   
    customer_id=request.POST['customer_id']
    customer_obj= Customer.objects.get(customer_id=customer_id)
    special_instructions=request.POST['special_instructions']
    company=company_label
    
    #invoice total
    total=  100 #request.POST['total']
    CGST= 10 #request.POST['CGST']
    SGST= 10 #request.POST['SGST']
    discount=10 # request.POST['discount']
    round_off= 100 #request.POST['round_off']
    grand_total=100 #request.POST['grand_total']
    
    #other details
    user=username
    print(user)
    user_obj = User.objects.get(username=user)
    print(user_obj)

    remarks=request.POST['remarks']
    sales_details=Sales_Invoice.objects.create(invoice_number=invoice_number,invoice_date=invoice_date,customer_id=customer_obj,company=company,special_instructions=special_instructions,total=total,CGST=CGST,SGST=SGST,discount=discount,round_off=round_off,grand_total=grand_total,user=user_obj,remarks=remarks)
    sales_details.save()   
    
    total_sales = Sales_Invoice.objects.filter(company=company_label).all().count() + 1
    new_gen_invoice_number=f"{company_label}-{month}{year}-{total_sales}"
    
    #ITEM DETAILS
    sales_invoice_id = gen_invoice_number
    sales_invoice_id_obj=Sales_Invoice.objects.get(invoice_number=sales_invoice_id)
    item = request.POST['item']
    item_obj= New_Stock_Entry.objects.get(item=item)
    hsn = request.POST['hsn']
    quantity = request.POST['quantity']
    tax_code = request.POST['tax_code']
    

    unit_name = request.POST['unit_name']
    unit_obj = Unit_Setting.objects.get(unit_name=unit_name)

    unit_price = request.POST['unit_price']
    amount = request.POST['amount']
    
    items=Items_Details.objects.create(sales_invoice_id=sales_invoice_id_obj,item=item_obj,hsn=hsn,quantity=quantity,unit_name=unit_obj,unit_price=unit_price,tax_code=tax_code,amount=amount)
    items.save()
```

Comment: use django inlineformset_factory(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). then you just save two forms in view

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło but we are doing it by using python django queryset. is there any way to do with queryset?